# LINQ Grouping Based On Complex Condition

Tags: c#, linq

```
 public class SpecialClass
{
    public int property1;
    public ListAttributes attributes = new ListAttributes();
}


 public class ListAttributes
    {
        public List<a> aList = new List<a>();
        public List<b> bList = new List<b>();
        public List<c> cList = new List<c>();
        public List<d> dList = new List<d>();
    }
```

I have a List of `SpecialClass` objects. I want to group them such that each `SpecialClass` object having the same `aList`, `bList`, `cList` and `dList` will be in the same group.

Condition for these lists to be equal can be expressed as:

```
var areEquivalent = !list1.Except(list2).Union(list2.Except(list1)).Any();
```

In other words, these distinct lists should have the same members regardless of their place in the list.

How can this be done using LINQ? (I would appreciate it if it can be expressed as lambda expressions but query expressions form is also welcome)

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you created an equality mechanism for the `ListAttributes` class

Comment: If you want to using `GroupBy` you need to create a function that will returns equals value for equivalent lists (in your case for 4 list).
By the way, I suggest use this condition on equivalention: 
`var areEquivalent = list1.Count == list2.Count && list1.Intersect(list2).Count() == list1.Count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to write a custom `EqualityComparer`. This sample might get you started.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class ListAttributesEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ListAttributes>
{
    public bool Equals(ListAttributes x, ListAttributes y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        // You should also do null checks on aList etc, but I have left those out for brevity
        var result = x.aList.Count == y.aList.Count && x.bList.Count == y.bList.Count && x.cList.Count == y.cList.Count &&
                     x.dList.Count == y.dList.Count;
        result = result && !x.aList.Except(y.aList).Union(y.aList.Except(x.aList)).Any();
        result = result && !x.bList.Except(y.bList).Union(y.bList.Except(x.bList)).Any();
        result = result && !x.cList.Except(y.cList).Union(y.cList.Except(x.cList)).Any();
        result = result && !x.dList.Except(y.dList).Union(y.dList.Except(x.dList)).Any();
        return result;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ListAttributes obj)
    {
        return (obj?.aList?.Distinct()?.Count() ?? 0).GetHashCode();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<SpecialClass>();

        // Populate list here

        var results = list.GroupBy(g => g.attributes, new ListAttributesEqualityComparer());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class SpecialClass
{
    public int property1;
    public ListAttributes attributes = new ListAttributes();
}

public class ListAttributes
{
    public List<int> aList = new List<int>();
    public List<string> bList = new List<string>();
    public List<double> cList = new List<double>();
    public List<DateTime> dList = new List<DateTime>();
}
```

*Also consider simplifying your existing comparison to use `Intersect` like mentioned in the comments of your original question.*

Comment: What is the logic behind (obj?.aList?.Distinct()?.Count() ?? 0).GetHashCode();

Comment: A great question @JohnL. For two objects to be considered `Equal` - `Equals` needs to return `true` and `GetHashCode` needs to return the same value. GetHashCode is used for dictionary / hashset bucketing (which Except will use behind the scenes, for example). The challenge with your scenario is how to calculate that HashCode relatively quickly. So in my case, I've decided to calculate the HashCode based on the number of distinct items in the `aList` (it needs to be based on the distinct count due to how `Except` works). The ? and ?? are basically just there in case the `aList` is null.